# Change default logging implementation in Helidon

Tags: helidon

I would like to use `log4j` with `Helidon`. Is there any way to change default logging implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Helidon, we have decided to use to use Java Util Logging (JUL), to allow our users to choose any logging implementation.
There are bridges for most implementations for JUL. For log4j, you can have a look at this page: 
http://people.apache.org/~psmith/logging.apache.org/sandbox/jul-log4j-bridge/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

With Helidon 2.0 you will need:

Add dependency log4j2

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

when start your application, add this variables using external configuration log4j:

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/conf/log4j2.xml

java  -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/conf/log4j2.xml -jar target/your-app.jar
```

Or when your log4j2.xml is inside src/main/resources/log4j2.xml

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager

java  -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager -jar target/your-app.jar
```

Example log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p %c{1.} %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="io.helidon" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: how can we change the log level at runtime?

Comment: Please make sure your log4j version is 2.16.0 or higher wherever you use it.